# How to get access to the Internet using Huawei USB Modem?

Tags: windows-7, networking

How to get access to the Internet using Huawei USB Modem?

I am running Windows 7.
I have a Huawei E3372 Mobile Broadband LTE USB Stick.
When I plug it in to my computer's USB 3 port, the light is solid cyan. Service is active.
I can access the setup page.
Data is flowing to and from the Internet Service Provider (T-Mobile).

If I leave my computer connected to my local connection (cable) I have Local Area Connection 2 listed.
When I plug in my Huawei USB Stick, I get a second connection called Local Area Connection 6.
Now if I disable Local Area Connection 2 and leave Local Area Connection 6 enabled, I get no Internet connectivity.
If I re-enable Local Area Connection 2, Internet connectivity returns.

What do I need to do to get connectivity activated from the USB Stick?

Once a few days ago, I was able to ping 8.8.8.8 and tracert 8.8.8.8 successfully.
Now it does nothing.
It times out.

I tried to bridge connection 2 and connection 6.
That did not work either.

Comment: Are you sure your LAN connection wasn't enabled a few days ago, without, you realizing it?

Comment: A few days ago, I was able to ping and tracert to 8.8.8.8, but I was not able to surf the web. As if the connection was not fully established?

Comment: That doesn’t make sense.   Your inability to surf was a different problem.  You didn’t answer my question though.

Comment: What happens if you go back to basics and repair install your Huawei software/drivers?

Comment: Back to basics is right.
First I got rid of the StraightTalk SIM card and bought a T-Mobile SIM card. The tech support people at StraightTalk said they do not work on WiFi hotspots. It's not really a hotspot, but who am I to argue? StraightTalk SIM cards only work on cell phones.
After installing the T-Mobile SIM card The Huawei E3372 worked fine.
I did not have to install any supplemental software.
By the way, there are no drivers available to download for this product.
Windows recognized the device and connected to the Internet.